# Can you use an extension cord for Induction Cooktop and any Mosquito Repllent device?

Tags: power-electronics, electricity

I have [this](https://www.amazon.in/Philips-High-Extension-Chord-2-Meter/dp/B00V69FBHG) kind of extension cord. And I have [this](https://www.flipkart.com/philips-hd4928-01-induction-cooktop/p/itmeyftvf6mf6cac?pid=ICTDGRVGPEJP857U&lid=LSTICTDGRVGPEJP857UPB1ZWI&marketplace=FLIPKART&spotlightTagId=TrendingId_j9e%2Fm38%2F575&srno=b_1_1&otracker=browse&iid=289a8244-e426-4aab-92a8-e6e2806bfbb0.ICTDGRVGPEJP857U.SEARCH&ppt=browse&ppn=browse&ssid=ooown20sr40000001588786621864) 2000 W induction cooktop.

The mosquito repellent I mentioned is like this:
[image]

Can I use them safely on extension cord instead of using them directly on socket (like we do normally)?

Once my friend used extension for a cooler and extension cord got damaged. Some say you shouldn't use it for coolers and fridge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'll bite.

The cord needs to be rated for the current required for your load.

Total load would be:

- Cooktop: 2000W/240V = 8.3A
- Bug juice vaporizer: about 5W, so 5/240V = 0.021A

So adding the vaporizer isn't the issue. It's the rating on the cord being adequate for the cooktop. The linked Amazon page for the cord doesn't give a current rating. You will need to check.

It's likely that the strip you have isn't adequate for the cooktop; you will need a heavier cord to be safe.

Comment: So many products on Amazon are devoid of specifications that I hesitate to order anything electrical. My advice to @Vikas is: don't buy anything electrical unless you have specifications!

Comment: Okay. What means heavier cord in simple words? Also, are their special cords for items like these?

Comment: @JYelton I'm not buying them, I already have similar things.

Comment: 2000W is a large load. I would use a dedicated cord suitable for a construction power tool with a direct run back to the socket, with no 'power strip' in between. If you need the vaporizer near the cooker, run a separate lightweight cord to it, perhaps off a nearby lighting circuit.

Comment: @Vikas You might find this other question interesting because it deals with powering things over extension cords and power strips. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/468307/2028

Comment: And.. closed question. @Vikas, at least you got your answer, and that's what really counts.